# Как преобразовать datetime в aware datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Получаю такую дату: `2019-10-11 12:33:42`, она содержит тип `datetime.datetime`.

Как мне её преобразовать в `aware datetime`?

Почитав документацию ничего такого не нашел. Только такой вариант: `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

Пробовал сделать так, чтобы перевести в `aware datetime`, но это не работает.

```
aware_datetime = datetime(date_parsed, timezone.utc)
```

В переменной `date_parsed` хранится такая дата: `2019-10-11 12:33:42`

Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Аналогичный вопрос на англоязычной версии SO...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python)

Примеры:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT
from datetime import timezone

dt = DT.strptime("2019-10-11 12:33:42", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt_aware = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print(dt)
print(dt_aware)
```

---

```
In [32]: print(dt)
2019-10-11 12:33:42

In [33]: print(dt_aware)
2019-10-11 12:33:42+00:00
```

---

Также можно воспользоваться модулем pytz:

```
import pytz

dt_aware = pytz.utc.localize(dt)
print(dt_aware)
```

---

```
In [37]: print(dt_aware)
2019-10-11 12:33:42+00:00

In [38]: dt_aware
Out[38]: datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 11, 12, 33, 42, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: Хочу выразить огромную благодарность вам ! Теперь буду использовать ваш ответ как шпаргалку для работы со временем ! Еще раз огромная благодарность вам !!

Comment: @Raharasomaha, всегда рад помочь)